# Aggregate data in two columns in SAS

Tags: sas, aggregate, data-manipulation

I have a SAS dataset that looks something like this:

```
ID FirstName LastName AmountPaid AmountOwed
1  John      Doe      2,134      2,134
1  John      Doe      2,134      0
1  John      Doe      2,134      2,134
2  Jake      Smith    705        120
2  Jake      Smith    500        320
```

I would like to aggregate the data by AmountPaid and AmountOwed so that the resulting dataset is:

```
ID FirstName LastName AmountPaid AmountOwed
1  John      Doe      6,402      4,268
2  Jake      Smith    1,205      440
```

Comment: What have you tried? https://video.sas.com/detail/video/5537540644001/the-summary-statistics-task-in-sas%C2%AE-studio?autoStart=true&q=summary%20task

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data have;
input ID FirstName $ LastName $ AmountPaid AmountOwed;
datalines;
1 John Doe 2134 2134
1 John Doe 2134 0
1 John Doe 2134 2134
2 Jake Smith 705 120
2 Jake Smith 500 320
;

proc summary data = have nway;
   class ID FirstName LastName;
   var amount:;
   output out = want(drop = _:) sum =;
run;
```